# remove git secrets from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, git-secret

I have added git secrets to ubuntu(16.04 LTS) and it was working fine until I was executing these commands,

```
git secrets --register-aws
git secrets --install ~/.git-templates/git-secrets
git config --global init.templateDir ~/.git-templates/git-secrets
```

I have removed these files,

```
~/.git-templates/git-secrets
/usr/bin/git-secrets
```

from my environment, but still it seems not working fine.

```
git secrets --scan , gives nothing
```

How do I remove git-secrets permanently from my PC and re-install or solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Currently we need to do this manually.

1. Delete `secrets` from `.git/config` for all local repositories.
2. Delete `secrets` from `.gitconfig`.
3. Remove `commit-msg`, `pre-commit` and `prepare-commit-msg` hooks from all git repositories.
4. Change/remove git template so that it does not configure these hooks for newer repos.
5. Uninstall binary. Following are the multiple places you can look in the Linux based machine.

   i. By default all the `git core` command scripts are available in `/usr/lib/git-core/` directory.

   ii. Apart from that, you can check in `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/local/bin/` directories as well.

   iii. If you are still **NOT** able to find the binary, then type `which git-secrets` to identify the place where actually `git-secrets` is installed.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets/issues/95#issuecomment-676518408) created for the same in GitHub. You can check the progress in there as well.